# This is not an error but this getchar() function gives previous array's value why?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char a[10],b[10];
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    a[i]=getchar();
  }
  for(int j=10;j<10;j++)
  {
    b[i]=getchar();
  }
  printf("%s",b);
}
```

In the above code the print section prints also the string `a`. Can you please explain why?

Comment: The contents of `b` are never set because the body of the second `for` loop never runs. Accessing an uninitalised buffer is Undefined Behaviour. UB means the behaviour is unpredictable and the result can be anything.

Answer (score 4):

First, let us suppose true code is `for(int j=0;j<10;j++)` and not `for(int j=10;j<10;j++)`

> In the above code the print section prints also the string a pls explain why?

*Undefined behavior* (UB).

`"%s"` expects a matching pointer to a *string*.  Array `b` does not contain a *string* as it lacks a *null character* <sup>1</sup>.  Result: UB.

Likely code just kept on printing nearby data which happened to be the contents of `a` until it eventually encounter a *null character* somewhere.

Instead, append a *null character* or limit printing.

```
printf("%.10s",b);
// or
for(int j=0;j<(10-1);j++) {  // start at 0 and up to 10-1
  b[i]=getchar();
}
b[10-1] = '\0';
printf("%s",b);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> `a` is not a string either as it too lacks a null character.

Comment: Tq bro this is very useful